# Proper way to create a radiobuttonlist without having any of the radiobuttons checked by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The nullable identifier makes the radiobuttonlist not check any of the radiobuttons by default on first page load. Is this the proper way to handle this scenario? Or what is best practice?

Model:

```
[Required]
public SomeEnum? Choices { get; set; }

public enum SomeEnum
{
    OptionOne,
    OptionTwo
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Choices)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Choices, SomeEnum.OptionOne)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Choices, SomeEnum.OptionTwo)
</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div>
    <input name="Choices" id="Choices" type="radio" data-val-required="The Choices field is required." data-val="true" value="OptionOne"></input>
    <input name="Choices" id="Choices" type="radio" value="OptionTwo"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: For radio buttons, best practice is to add a button **None** when that option is applicable.

Comment: @abatishchev by removing 'MVC' word from topic/subject.. won't that affect google crawler bot and rank the page/question lower in search results? Because I think it's really important to have that word in the url and now it is gone.

Comment: This a common mispractice to put a tag into title, and a common practice to remove it :) Tag line is for tags specially. Also most popular tag (c# in this case) will be put automatically. And don't be afraid proper tagging is much more important than titling.

Comment: I see your point but I still see removing the word MVC from the URL affecting google ranking. At least that is what I have learned during my days of a web developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using the best model to represent a radio list with no default value. This is exactly the right purpose for `null`.

An advantage of this approach is that the `[Required]` attribute makes it easy to validate that an option has been selected.

Comment: Could you please explain that last paragraph in more detail? I think I understand it but not 100% sure since I haven't tested the None option. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to be clearer. An alternative (less effective) approach would be to add an enum value called `None` as the default option. You wouldn't render a radio button for this option, but it would prevent options One and Two from being selected by default. A disadvantage of this strategy would be that the `[Required]` option would do nothing.

Comment: Exellent, now I totally understand! Thanks for the clarification!